# How to use explode and get first element in one line in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$beforeDot = explode(".", $string)[0];
```

This is what I'm attempting to do, except that it returns syntax error. If there is a workaround for a one liner, please let me know. If this is not possible, please explain.

Comment: What PHP version are you using? Array dereferncing was first added to 5.4 AFAIK.

Comment: You realise that PHP version 5.1.4 is 8 years old, and officially deceased (unsupported)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [function array dereferencing](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing) was implemented in PHP 5.4, so if you are using an older version you'll have to do it another way.

Here's a simple way to do it:

```
$beforeDot = array_shift(explode('.', $string));
```

Comment: Love this one liner! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 12):

You can use [list](http://php.net/list) for this:

```
list($first) = explode(".", "foo.bar");
echo $first; // foo
```

This also works if you need the second (or third, etc.) element:

```
list($_, $second) = explode(".", "foo.bar");
echo $second; // bar
```

But that can get pretty clumsy.

Answer (score 12):

Use [current()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php), to get first position after explode:

```
$beforeDot = current(explode(".", $string));
```

Comment: Thanks. Note that 'reset' will be useful to ensure that the pointer is always at the first element and the substring returned is the first element but here ( for  a one liner ) it wont be useful bcos it cannot accept a function in its argument.

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_shift()` for this purpose :

```
$beforeDot = array_shift(explode(".", $string));
```

Comment: `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference` : also if `[0]` doesn't work for `explode()` then OP has PHP < 5.4.0 and it won't work with `array_values()`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver : I've already understood it reading manual about `5.4` version, thank you all :) Updated.

Answer (score 1):

in php <= 5.3 you need to use

```
$beforeDot = explode(".", $string);
$beforeDot = $beforeDot[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Pairing 'explode' with  'implode' to populate a variable.

explode -> break the string into an array at the separator
implode -> get a string from  that first array element into a variable

```
$str = "ABC.66778899";
$first = implode(explode('.', $str, -1));
```

Will give you 'ABC' as a string.
Adjust the limit argument in explode as per your string characteristics.

Comment: Unfortunately this will return `"ABC66778899"` if the input string contains *more than one* `.`, like in `$str="ABC.66778899.ext"`. The `-1` in `explode()` basically only removes the last found element from the array generated by the "explode" action.

Comment: @cars10m - Thats why in my answer  I  mentioned -> Adjust the limit argument in explode as per your string characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the limit parameter in the explode function

> explode($separator, $str, $limit)

```
$txt = 'the quick brown fox';
$explode = explode(' ', $txt, -substr_count($txt, ' '));
```

This will return an array with only one index that has the first word which is "the"

[PHP Explode docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Explanation:

> If the limit parameter is negative, all components except the last
> -limit are returned.

So to get only the first element despite the number of occurences of the substr you use -substr_count